# Magento bundle dropdown need to display out of stock

Tags: php, magento, drop-down-menu, bundle

In a bundle product page, I need to display if a product in the bundle is out of stock. Currently, the product is simply not appearing in the dropdown. I've looked at the "select.phtml" file and found at the beginning that this line of code get the option value for the dropdown :

```
<?php $_selections  = $_option->getSelections(); ?>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't fetch "out of stock" items. So, is there a way to include these items?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hoping this can help someone. After searching for hours, finally found the line that was causing the problem inside app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Block/View/Type/Bundle.php

You need to change this line

```
$this->_options = $optionCollection->appendSelections($selectionCollection, false,
            Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getSkipSaleableCheck()
        );
```

to this

```
$this->_options = $optionCollection->appendSelections($selectionCollection, false,
        true        
        //Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getSkipSaleableCheck()
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on SimCity's answer, rather than extending/overwriting the block, you can do the following. I have added this code to the top of bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/options.phtml

```
// Get the current value of SkipSaleableCheck
<?php $skipSaleableCheck = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getSkipSaleableCheck() ?>
// Overwrite this value with a 'true' value
<?php Mage::helper('catalog/product')->setSkipSaleableCheck(true) ?>
```

You can then reset this value at the bottom of the same file using the following code:

```
<?php Mage::helper('catalog/product')->setSkipSaleableCheck($skipSaleableCheck) ?>
```

This method provides the same result without having to overwrite core Magento blocks.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.8.1 you find the file in app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle.php

Be aware of making changes in the core will get you site no good for updates. Make a copy of your file to your local directory.